# How to get object id given its name using a JMeter regex?

Tags: regex, jmeter

A Cometd response is returned after a request in JMeter. This response contains:
"data":{"elements":[{"id":1, "name":"name1",...},{"id":2, name":"name2",...},...]}
How can I get the id value for a given name value using a regex in JMeter, e.g. 1 for name1, 2 for name2?

Comment: Looks like `"id":(\d+)[^{}\[\]]*?"<name you want to find>"` might work.

Comment: In jmeter 3.0 you have json path , where you can give json path as elements[0].id  and reference name as reference_id ..then you can use this as ${reference_id}  or any related json plugins. refer the famous blog by dimiti T https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "id":([0-9]), "name":"give the name you want"

Try this which will work for the example which has been given by you.
"data":{"elements":[{"id":1, "name":"name1",...},{"id":2, "name":"name2",...},...]}

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) it is much more suitable for dealing with JSON data than Regular Expression Extractor.

The relevant JSON Path Query will look like:

```
$.data[?(@.name == 'name1')].id
```

Use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to check the extracted values.

If you have already upgraded to the brand new [Apache JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you can use "JSON Path Tester" mode of the View Results Tree listener.

[image: JMeter 3.0]

Comment: This won't work, as the response is not a proper JSON, so I need a classical regex.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following regex to solve the issue: 
\\"id\\":(\d+)[^{}[]]*?\\”name\d\\"